# How to create Office COM Add-in, which is deployable without admin rights

Tags: c#, office-interop, office-addins, excel-addins, word-addins

I am looking for an approach to develop a MS Office (Excel, Word, PowerPoint, etc.) addin. The addin is required to be written in C# or C/C++ and deployable in which end users can install it without administrator privilege.

There are a few working example such as [Think-cell](https://www.think-cell.com/en/) and [Eikon](https://www.thomsonreuters.co.jp/ja/financial/products/tools-applications/trading-investment-tools/eikon-trading-software/eikon-download.html). But I don't know how they archived it.

After some research, I'm aware of the following ways to create an add-in, but none of them does not meet the requirement.

### 1. Use Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)

It seems that installing a VSTO plugin does not require admin rights, but it needs VSTO runtime to be installed and the runtime installer requires admin rights.

### 2. Implement the IDTExensibility2 interface

In this case, the DLL can be placed in somewhere like `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\` without admin rights, but eventually the DLL must be

1. registered under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` as a normal COM, and
2. registered under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\(PowerPoint|Excel|Word|Outlook|etc.)\Addins`.

Here, the problem is the first registration requires admin rights.

**So, is there any other ways to develop an office addin that does not require admin rights when installed, like Think-Cell and Eikon?**

Note: I am OK with using .NET as recent Windows 8/10 has .NET runtime pre-installed. But it seems that .NET is not required, as seen in Think-cell and Eikon, to create an addin that does not require admin rights when installed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question which I needed to answer myself. My solution was a small batch script which copies the files to a user-accessible directory (under the %appdata% directory) and puts all infos into the registry afterwards. Please note: With the `reg` command you can write into the registry without admin rights (as long as it is in HKCU). In order to provide the right path into the registry key it locates the target directory and puts it into the registry file instead of the placeholder.

So let me just give you the code which I used for my software SlideFab as a kind of backup installer if no admin rights were available. This script might not be pretty and has no error handling but it works.

```
@echo off
echo ___________________________________________________________
echo Welcome to the SlideFab installer batch
echo ___________________________________________________________
echo This batch will install SlideFab 2 for the active user only
echo No system files will be touched
echo ___________________________________________________________
echo IMPORTANT: Do not run this install batch from the zip file
echo            directly. It won't work. Please extract the zip 
echo            file contents to a folder and run it from there.
echo   
echo For further information visit https://SlideFab.com
echo ___________________________________________________________
:Ask
echo Would you like install SlideFab 2?(Y/N)
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
If /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto yes 
If /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto no 
goto Ask
:yes
set "sourcepath=%cd%"
set installfolder="SlideFab 2"
set installpath="%appdata%\SlideFab 2"

cd %appdata%
rmdir /S /Q %installfolder%
mkdir %installfolder%

cd %sourcepath%

robocopy "SlideFab 2" %installpath% /E

powershell "(Get-Content SlideFab.reg) | foreach-object {($_ -replace \"FOLDER_APP_DATA\", (\"%appdata%\").replace(\"\\\",\"\\\\\"))} | foreach-object {($_ -replace \"FILEPATH_APP_DATA\", (\"%appdata%\").replace(\"\\\",\"/\"))} | Set-Content SlideFabLocalized.reg"


reg import SlideFabLocalized.reg

del SlideFabLocalized.reg

echo SlideFab 2 was installed
pause
exit
:no
echo SlideFab 2 was not installed
pause
```

And the registry entry looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\PowerPoint\Addins\HuehnSolutions.SlideFab2]
"FriendlyName"="SlideFab2"
"Description"="SlideFab. The most powerful Powerpoint automation tool ever built"
"Manifest"="FOLDER_APP_DATA\\SlideFab 2\\SlideFab2.vsto|vstolocal"
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTO\Security\Inclusion\a6cf3786-79d9-47b1-a547-d4f03100b58d]
"Url"="file:///FILEPATH_APP_DATA/SlideFab 2/SlideFab2.vsto"
"PublicKey"="<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>seBB06Hh+Io1QcLLu2OVLl761vIeB4PDMAKlHDRlS9TVD0RZU4tBZ4ty22npfRhvt1Uqm5b8At7GZpQrLuMtX1AAvjmoy9qlm7NsX95UCFBP8ip//YvupVmcVpg7okAzuKALBu3anJGC1aa+Q57h6IP3cDnfdswoCvC1e9KJKpSmzktXG29MQ3nQBLn7Oo3UUM4C9Om8h/96cjowiI8FdHuz6JXIj8K8OEEhtCWxGnIL2ebYvnrPxBRFIlBHkuDeGHZ2C0hJB4MWN6MkTQEkJp5YtfJrt1oDmYPvlVjzp3gcUHcLft2/1gLnOVJFMDrwBM93YZNetQAuwzQdgxesHQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>"
```

Comment: Also, if you need to write to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (seemingly necessary when dealing with a COM DLL), you can substitute that in the .reg file with HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes and it should work perfectly for the current user. If there is a 32 bit version available of the DLL, you can generate a .reg file with Visual Studio's regcap.exe

Comment: See an example of what I mean here: https://github.com/theduffster/KeepOutlookRunning/blob/main/KeepOutlookRunning-64bit.reg